# How to apply themes to WindowsForm in C#?

Tags: c#, winforms, controls, themes, skin

This question is in my head for way too long. How this guy made a form with a custom border and custom controls without a ".dll" file or something like that. It's just a ".exe".

**My question is simple:** How can I do this to my forms?

[image]

Comment: Is that screenshot winforms or WPF? http://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/clsDevExpressLookAndFeelDefaultLookAndFeeltopic

Comment: It is winforms. I'll take a look on your link, thank you.

Comment: I dont think you will get around the DLL dependancy unless you use [ILMERGE](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/people/mbarnett/ilmerge.aspx) to combine the DLL into the EXE.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you mean without dll file but I would recommend checking out 
Drawing Custom Borders in Windows Forms

http://customerborderform.codeplex.com/

Comment: I mean the application is a ".exe" alone, it doesn't need any ".fsl" or ".dll" to load the themes.

Comment: I think this is a nice library otherwise you need to have another app with you project

Answer (score 0):

The fact that it is just a dll doesn't mean it doesn't rely on a 3rd party application. The developer could have merged them in the dll, you can check if there are resouces/assmblies merged into the dll using [ILMerge](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/9364/Merging-NET-assemblies-using-ILMerge) or if it is a WPF app, using [other means](http://code.google.com/p/costura/).

Other than using a 3rd party control or using GDI+ to custom draw your form/controls, there's no out of the box support for skins/themes in WinForm controls, except for what OS supports.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, do you know a good free 3rd party application that supports custom controls and border?